# How to implement Flutter api json data to a list view at 3rd level category?

Tags: laravel, flutter

I'm trying to build a flutter app, the idea is to have:

1. List of Hospitals and a Hospital has many doctors.
2. Doctors are categories by departments, Example: Cardiology department, Neurology department.

The idea is to have a list of hospitals list from api json data, after clicking a specific hospital, there should be list of departments (api json data) and after selecting a specific department from the list - it will load all the doctors in a list from that department.

Can anyone help please? I'm using Laravel 9 as a backend.

Answer (score 0):

don't know if it can help you

```
- Json code
    
    {
        "hospital":[
           {
            "name": "hospital1",
            "department":[
                {
                    "name": "department1",
                    "doctors":[
                        {
                            "name": "doctor1"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "name": "doctor2"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                 {
                    "name": "department2",
                    "doctors":[
                        {
                            "name": "doctor1"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "name": "doctor2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
               
           },
            {
            "name": "hospital2",
            "department":[
                {
                    "name": "department1",
                    "doctors":[
                        {
                            "name": "doctor1"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "name": "doctor2"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                 {
                    "name": "department2",
                    "doctors":[
                        {
                            "name": "doctor1"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "name": "doctor2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
               
           } 
        ]
    }
    - Dart code
    
    class DataResponse{
            DataResponse({
                this.hospital,
            });
        
            List<Hospital> hospital;
        
            factory DataResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Welcome(
                hospital: List<Hospital>.from(json["hospital"].map((x) => Hospital.fromJson(x))),
            );
        
            Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
                "hospital": List<dynamic>.from(hospital.map((x) => x.toJson())),
            };
        }
        
        class Hospital {
            Hospital({
                this.name,
                this.department,
            });
        
            String name;
            List<Department> department;
        
            factory Hospital.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Hospital(
                name: json["name"],
                department: List<Department>.from(json["department"].map((x) => Department.fromJson(x))),
            );
        
            Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
                "name": name,
                "department": List<dynamic>.from(department.map((x) => x.toJson())),
            };
        }
        
        class Department {
            Department({
                this.name,
                this.doctors,
            });
        
            String name;
            List<Doctor> doctors;
        
            factory Department.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Department(
                name: json["name"],
                doctors: List<Doctor>.from(json["doctors"].map((x) => Doctor.fromJson(x))),
            );
        
            Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
                "name": name,
                "doctors": List<dynamic>.from(doctors.map((x) => x.toJson())),
            };
        }
        
        class Doctor {
            Doctor({
                this.name,
            });
        
            String name;
        
            factory Doctor.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Doctor(
                name: json["name"],
            );
        
            Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
                "name": name,
            };
        }
```